# getting the highscore and set text

Tags: android, android-intent, copy, sharedpreferences, settext

I am creating a android quiz game that has a highscore button on my mainmeny.class.

The flow of my game is this.it has a timelimit to answer the question if he doesnt answer it within 5 sec he will be intent to my tryagain.class.

But if you answer or click the right image button you will be intent in the next level. what i want to my game is have a highscore that will count how many correct answer the user answered. example= 6/10. and will save it to my highscore.class. that will automatically settext.

```
public class EasyOne extends Activity {

ImageButton a, b, c;

Intent intent ;

CountDownTimer cdt;

TextView timer;

MediaPlayer player;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.easyone);

    a = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_a);

    b = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_b);

    c = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_c);

    timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_timer);

    cdt = new CountDownTimer(5000,1000) {


        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
               timer.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
              timer.setText("TIMES UP!");
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TimesUp.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    };

    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ChoiceTwo.class);
    a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(intent);


            cdt.cancel();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ChoiceTwo.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });


    cdt.start();
}
}
```

Comment: use sqlite to store the scores.

Comment: use shared  preferences to save your score data.

Comment: how can i dot that?newbie :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just keep a counter of the correct answers and once the ten questions has been answered you can just output the score out of 10 to a textView?

```
   int correct =0;
   int questionsAsked =0;

   public void correct(){
    correct++;
   }

   public void question(){
    if(questionsAsked == 10){
      result.setText(correct +"/10 Correct Answers.";
    }else{
    if(answer == questionAnswer){
         correct();
     }
       questionsAsked++;
    }
   }
```

Just a thought, if anything it may only be an idea to get you started. Also you can send the highscore to your highscore class by passing it with your intent when starting your new activity. Check this out, it will help you. [Passing data between activites](http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-using-intents-to-pass-data-and-return-results-between-activities/)